# HTML5 video element width and height attributes question

Tags: html

Can the html5 video elements width and height attributes have a pixel and percentage value?

If so are these the only values allowed?

Do I have to add the percentage and pixel prefixes at the end of the value?

Answer (score 13):

Based on the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/dimension-attributes.html#attr-dim-width) `width` and `height` define the video size in CSS pixels, not percentages. So setting a % value won't work.

```
<!-- No `px` at the end of the value like CSS -->
<video width="980" height="560" ... > ... </video>
```

It’s always best to specify the `height` and `width` attributes so that the page doesn’t need to reflow. If pixel values doesn't work for you, don't specify the video dimension attributes and instead use the style attributes to specify the `height` and `width` in percentage values.

```
<!-- Let's supposed you want the video to adjust to the size of its parent element -->
<video style="outline:none; width:100%; height:100%;" ... > ... </video>
```

If you don't specify the dimensions at all, the video will display at its original size.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HTML5 video has both. I think it scales according to the smallest value. For example, if you say "width='20%' height='50%'", it will scale everything to 20%.

Try it here [W3school video tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_all). If you want to use pixels, put 'px' at the end, for percentage use '%'.

Comment: Avoid W3schools, they're full of misinformation: http://w3fools.com/. Try Mozilla Developer Network (https://developer.mozilla.org/) or an HTML5 introductory site like HTML5 Doctor (http://htmldoctor.com) instead.

Comment: This is not valid HTML5. Orio's answer is the correct one.